# How to sync windows server folders with a AIX server using script?

Tags: files, batch-file, synchronization, aix, shell-scripting

Everyday I would like to sync the files and folders in the windows server with AIX server and vice versa. Does anyone suggest me, How I can write a shell or bat script to achieve this?

Comment: also asked on [stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7986571/7552)

Comment: @BioLounge: Please, do not crosspost your questions on more than one single StackExchange site.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [rsync](http://rsync.samba.org/) and search for this term here, you will find many tips regarding this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than sync files, why not make AIX write them to a Windows fileshare? Install bos.cifs from your base CD and update, then you can mount a Windows share on your AIX system and write normally.

Comment: This has the added benefit of not requiring AIX to have any control of the security of the fileshare. So have your Windows admin create a share with a dedicated account for AIX to have full read/write access, and then they can ACL users on at the Windows domain level instead of your trying to integrate something like Samba with Windows.